# Get Active directory user asynchonously

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, async-await

How can I query the Active directory asynchronously.
  I have a bit of code to get the users synchronously

```
    Dim UserName as string = ""
    Dim Password as string = ""
    Dim LDAPPath As String = ""
    Dim DirectoryE As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, UserName, Password)

    Dim RootDSE As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = globalroot
    Dim objSearch As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(RootDSE)
    Dim oResult As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection = Nothing
    'objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid")
    'objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")


    objSearch.Filter = "(&(objectcategory=user))"
    objSearch.PageSize = 500
    oResult = objSearch.FindAll
    For Each ldentry As SearchResult In oResult
        Console.WriteLine(ldentry.Properties("cn")(0).ToString)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET 4.5. Change your code to a function which returns a `SearchResultCollection`:

```
 Private Function GetAllUsers() As SearchResultCollection
        Dim UserName As String = ""
        Dim Password As String = ""
        Dim LDAPPath As String = ""
        Dim DirectoryE As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, UserName, Password)

        Dim RootDSE As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
        Dim objSearch As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(RootDSE)
        Dim oResult As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection = Nothing
        'objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid")
        'objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")

        objSearch.Filter = "(&(objectcategory=user))"
        objSearch.PageSize = 500
        Return objSearch.FindAll

    End Function
```

Then call it like this:

```
 Private Async Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click

        For Each ldentry As SearchResult In Await Task.Run(Function() GetAllUsers())
            Console.WriteLine(ldentry.Properties("cn")(0).ToString)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does Await cause a separate task to run in the background. So does Await task.run (function) return only SearchResultCollection or can we return a List(of Objects)

Comment: Await causes the program to asynchronously wait for the Task to return. You can return whatever you like so long as you wrap it in a Task